# Can I detect whether current Vim instance is launched by git?

Tags: git

My .vimrc does a lot of extra things I don't want to do if it's launched by git (for example, during commit), since the purpose of that Vim instance is very specific so it makes no sense to launch many windows I would launch in normal way.

Is there any way I can detect whether this instance is launched by git?

Comment: For the specific case of commits, the `FileType` is `gitcommit`. You can probably use an `autocmd` based on that.

Comment: git also adds a number of variables to the environment, so you could test for the existence of one of those variables to determine whether Vim was launched from git. E.g., `if exists("$GIT_DIR")`.

Comment: @muru That should really be an answer! Nice orthogonal alternatives :)

Comment: Are you saying that you automatically open multiple windows every time you launch Vim? Why do you do that?

Comment: @KyleStrand I launch nerdtree for example. since i almost always want it to be there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ git config --global core.editor "vim -Nu NONE"
```

tells Git to use Vim without sourcing your `vimrc` (`-u NONE`) and in "nocompatible" mode (`-N`).

And, well… you could even add something to start directly in insert mode:

```
$ git config --global core.editor "vim -Nu NONE -c startinsert"
```

Comment: wow, vim is too rich to learn.

Comment: Do we need `--noplugin` with `-u NONE`?

Comment: @muru, I could *swear* it was needed at some point but… not anymore. Whatever, let me edit my answer.

Comment: Why do you think its no longer needed?  The way plugins are loaded hasn't changed in many years.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, I *seem* to remember a situation where netrw was loaded even with `-u NONE`. Maybe my memory is flawed. Maybe something else was messing with my setup at the time…